# ejs: Could not find include include file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm a student doing a project.
I'm trying to get a list of books from the server and displaying them one by one using ejs.

The project structure:

```
 |
 |-----routes
 |       |-----index.js
 |-----views
 |       |
 |       |----catalogue.ejs
 |       |----partials
 |       |      |----card.ejs
 |       |
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/catalogue', function(req, res, next) {
  let books = [{ bookName: 'The Way of Kings',                  author: 'Brandon Sanderson',    price: 19.90,   id: '01' },
               { bookName: 'Words of Radiance',                 author: 'Brandon Sanderson',    price: 19.90,   id: '02' },
               { bookName: 'Oathbringer',                       author: 'Brandon Sanderson',    price: 19.90,   id: '03' },
               { bookName: '100 Paper Planes to fold & fly',    author: 'Usborne',              price: 13.90,   id: '04' },
               { bookName: 'Brain Games for Cleaver Kids',      author: 'Usborne',              price: 10.90,   id: '05' },
               { bookName: 'This is Going To Hurt',             author: 'Adam Kay',             price: 15.90,   id: '06' },
               { bookName: 'Normal People',                     author: 'Sally Ronney',         price: 10.90,   id: '07' },
               { bookName: 'Fahrenheit 451',                    author: 'Ray Bradbury',         price: 10.90,   id: '08' },
               { bookName: 'To be taught if fortunate',         author: 'Becky Chambers',       price: 9.90,    id: '09' },
               { bookName: 'The Better Sister',                 author: 'Alafer Burke',         price: 15.90,   id: '10' },
               { bookName: 'Crooked Kingdom',                   author: 'Leigh Bardugo',        price: 10.90,   id: '11' }
               ];

  res.render('catalogue', { books: books, page:'Catalogue', menuId:'catalogue'});
});
```

catalogue.ejs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <%- include partials/head %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <%- include partials/header %>
</header>
<%- include partials/menu %>

<% books.forEach(function(book) { %>
    <%- include ('partials/card',{book:book}) %>
<% }); %>

<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
    <h3><%= page %></h3>
    <br>
</div>

<footer>
    <%- include partials/footer %>
</footer>

</body>
<%- include partials/script %>
</html>
```

card.ejs:

```
<main class="card container">
    <div class="card">
        <p class="bookName"><%= book.bookName %></p>
        <p class="author"><%= book.author %></p>
        <p class="price">Price: <%= book.price %>$</p>
        <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
    </div>
</main>
```

when i run it like this it only shows me the error: Could not find include include file. I copied the loop template from the ejs documentation, so i don't get why isn't it working.

I tried to play around it a bit to see what the problem is, and i realized that when instead of the loop in catalogue i just include partials/card it works.
But if i try to add anything, even parentesis like: include (partials/card) it gives me the error. what could cause this?

Thanks for anyone who tries to help, i have a deadline.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
<%- include partials/header %>
```

not

```
<% include partials/header %>
```

<%- should be used to include a file

Comment: i changed it to <%- instead of <% but the error remains the same.

Comment: In case you're wondering why, the [docs](https://ejs.co/#docs) suggest: "You'll likely want to use the raw output tag (`<%-`) with your include to avoid double-escaping the HTML output." That said, this doesn't help if the file isn't found.